# Dell U2414H triple monitors not all on after wake up

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have a triple monitor setup with three DELL U2414H monitors running on Windows 10. They are hooked up in a daisy-chained multi-stream transport configuration (MST). I have not changed anything with the configuration and I have been using all three of them at the same time for several weeks just fine but when I woke up the computer just now, it only turns on two of the monitors consistently. If I turn one off, I can enable the other but not all three.

I tried these things with no success:

- Turning off/on the displays in different orders.
- Unplugging the displays and plugging them back in while the Windows is awake.
- Restarting the computer.
- Completely shutdown and startup the computer.

When booting up I do notice the BIOS information screen displays on all three. It's just when you get to the Windows login screen only two are ever on. It's just strange this just started happening just now but I have been rebooting and sleeping the computer for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing several more weird issues, rebooting, and trying random things that got me nowhere, I uninstalled all AMD catalyst software and reinstalled, rebooted, and was able to get the problem resolved (for now).